# Microsoft Entourage/Exchange Server problem: all objects disappeared from server - still in some form on the client

Tags: email, exchange-2007, export, corruption, mac

One of our employees works with Entourage on his MacBook Pro (OSX 10.6) accessing Exchange Server 2007. Last Friday morning, I think while working over a VPN, Entourage (I think it was Entourage) deleted all his objects (mail, calendar, contacts) **on the server** and while creating a lot of strange folders (starting with underscores) on the client.

The local data seems to be there, but not in a consistent form. Since the user's mailbox is rather big, I suspect, that there was some kind of "move" operation which did not complete. I tried to export the data, but the export stops because of a corrupted object. Is there a tool or another way to export or retrieve the local data?

---

**Edit** - FYI: we solved the problem getting his data from the previous night's backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the export-mailbox cmdlet, you can set a number of acceptable errors before the command is stopped and reported unsuccesfull. I would try and increase this number to see if that gives you a successfull export. (the parameter is -BadItemLimit).

Comment: The problem is that the data is on Entourage (in its local cache) *only*. It seems that it was deleted on the server.

Comment: okay. If this was on Windows/Outlook you could use a utility to convert the offline cache into a datafile (pst), but on the mac I'm at a loss.

If the data was truly deleted from the server, your probably looking at doing a mailbox restore from backup anyways.

I don't know if it helps, but Entourage has a builtin repair tool - as long as the data is gone from the server I doubt it will work, but at least it's there. I think you can start it by holding the apple key when starting Entourage.

Comment: Yes, I also think I'll have to restore from the server's backup. Thank you anyway!